# php maven invalid descriptors

Tags: php, zend-framework, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to follow the 10 minutes install guide for Maven & Zend (http://www.php-maven.org/branches/2.0-SNAPSHOT/php-zend-10min.html) but when I run "mvn package" on my project I get

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager getting plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin': Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.2' has an invalid descriptor:
1) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: org.phpmaven
2) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: maven-php-plugin
3) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 2.0.2
```

all the time.

I already try to delete my local repository, but it didn't work.

mvn package -e returns:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager getting plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin': Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:2.4.3' has an invalid descriptor:
1) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: org.phpmaven
2) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: maven-php-plugin
3) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 2.0.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the plugin manager getting plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin': Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:2.4.3' has an invalid descriptor:
1) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: org.phpmaven
2) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: maven-php-plugin
3) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 2.0.2
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1544)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1851)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.bindLifecycleForPackaging(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1311)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.constructLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1275)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:534)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:2.4.3' has an invalid descriptor:
1) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong group ID: org.phpmaven
2) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong artifact ID: maven-php-plugin
3) Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version: 2.0.2
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:330)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:224)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:184)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultPluginManager.java:1642)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the way the maven-php-plugin is declared in php-parent-pom/pom.xml

Edit this file and delete the <extensions> node, and add <extensions>true</extensions> to the maven-php-plugin <plugin> definition